# Android bluetooth sco not picking headset microphone after pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, microphone, pairing

I'm trying to correctly setup bluetooth SCO in my app. After many attempts it seems that I've found a way to enable it "almost" reliably, in the sense that it works almost always, but in one case: if I launch my app and AFTER this I pair the headset, the headset mic is not picked (the phone mic is picked instead), while the headset earphones are correctly picked.

If instead I pair the headset BEFORE launching the app, everything seems to work fine.

The strange thing is that, even when the phone mic is picked, calling getRoutedDevice() on my AudioRecord object returns the bluetooth headset.

I tried to use SetPreferredDevice on the AudioRecord object, but apparently it has no effect.

The only way I found to ALWAYS pick the headset microphone is to call

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
```

However in this case, the output comes from the phone speaker and not from the BT headset earphones!

If instead i call:

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

the output comes consistently (and correctly) from the BT headset earphones, but I have the above mentioned mic issue (pairing the headset after launching the app, the phone mic is picked instead of the BT headset one).

The sequence I am using is:

1. I have a thread that checks if a bluetooth headset is connected and works pretty much reliably.
2. When isHeadsetConnected is true I do:

   arec.stop();       // my AudioRecord object

   atrack.stop();     // my AudioTrack object

   audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

   audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
3. In the listener of AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, when I receive SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED) I do:

   audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);

   atrack.play();

   arec.startRecording();

After struggling a lot, this seems to be the "almost" perfect sequence, with the caveat that it does not work fully if the first pairing is made with the application running.

I've made an attempt to pair the same headset during a Whatsapp call, and the bluetooth headset starts without any problem both input and output, so THERE MUST be a way to accomplish this!

I have read tons of questions/answers but none of these seems to consistently solve my problem.

I am using Android 11 on a CAT S62 Pro.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @Walid, nothing yet. The only thing that improved a little bit the situation was to create the AudioRecord as: 
new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION...

Unfortunately on some phone models the method fails and I am not able to instantiate another AudioRecord in MIC mode without restarting the application

Comment: Okay, thank you for your response Marcello!